# Proving a system of functions is orthogonal

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality

> Show that $$\{ e^{inx}/\sqrt{2\pi} : n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is an orthogonal system of functions on $[0, 2\pi]$.

In lecture it was stated that a system of functions $\varphi_n$ is orthogonal on $[a, b]$ if:

$$
\int_a^b \varphi_{m}(x) \overline{\varphi_{n}(x)} \, dx = \begin{cases}
1\quad &\text{for } n=m \\
0\quad &\text{for } n\neq m.
\end{cases}
$$

Thus, if we simply take

$$\overline{\varphi_n(x)} = \frac{e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}},$$

then:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \varphi_m(x) \overline{\varphi_n(x)} \, dx = 1 \text{ for } n=m$$

but it does not seem to be equal to $0$ for $n\neq m$.

Is my $\overline{\varphi_n(x)}$ wrong, is my definition wrong, or is there something else going on here?

**edit:** I have $\varphi_m(x) \overline{\varphi_n(x)}$ = $1/2\pi$ for $m=n$ so that the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives 1.

However, for $m\neq n$ I'm getting $\varphi_m(x) \overline{\varphi_n(x)}$ = $e^{m-n} / 2\pi$ so that the integral simply gives $e^{m-n}$. Surely this isn't equal to $0$...

Also, thank you to Michael Hardy for fixing notation!

Comment: Everything looks fine, double check your integration.  You will eventually need to use the fact that $e^{2n\pi i} = 1$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: @DMcMor there's the problem - didn't use that fact. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{imx} e^{-inx} \,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(m-n)x} \, dx = \left. \frac{e^{i(m-n)x}}{i(m-n)} \right|_{x:=0}^{x:=2\pi} = \frac{1-1}{i(m-n)} =0.
$$

Comment: I think my mistake was forgetting $e^{in2\pi} = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, thank you!